# Possible to use Android MediaMuxer to overlay an audio clip?

Tags: android, audio, video

I am trying to add a short audio clip on top of a video clip.  I have been able to use Android's `MediaMuxer` to combine a .mp4 with video only and a .mp4 with audio only, but my current task is to overlay an .mp4 audio clip on top of a video+audio .mp4 clip in the middle.  I have tried using the `mp4parser` library that has been suggested in other threads but have found troubles with that route (`SampleDescriptionBoxes` never match).

My idea was to use `writeSampleData()` to the `MediaMuxer` with data extracted from separate .mp4 clips.  I would write the audio from the original video, then at the given point start writing the new audio.  Finally, I would return to the audio from the original video again.  Does anyone know if this is feasible?  I am having troubles mostly because I don't understand how `presentationTimeUs` is supposed to work and the result is not streamable.

Any suggestions/help are appreciated!

Comment: Okay, if anyone knows of a way to combine audio into a video clip in Android in any way that would useful as well.  Many threads suggest mp4parser and I am able to merge/split videos, but not quite figure out what I need exactly.  I have yet to try ffmpeg, so I will be trying that  next.